# Proving a sequence of numbers in binomial

Tags: measure-theory, binomial-coefficients

Consider the set $P_r={n\choose r}p^r(1-p)^{n-r}$

Prove that: $$\sum_{r=1}^nrP_r=np$$

By far I attempted:

$$\sum_{r=1}^nr{n\choose r}p^r(1-p)^{n-r}=\sum_{r=1}^nn{n-1\choose r-1}p^r(1-p)^{n-r}$$
$$=\sum_{r=1}^n{n\choose r-1}p*p^{r-1}(1-p)(1-p)^{n-r-1}$$
$$=p(1-p)\sum_{r=1}^n{n\choose r-1}p^{r-1}(1-p)^{n-r-1}$$
$$p(1-p)(p+1-p)^n=p(p-1)(1)^n$$
$$-p^2+p$$

and this is where I am confused in. A bit of help checking of my work is very helpful please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You arrived at:$$\sum_{r=1}^nrP_r=\sum_{r=1}^nn{n-1\choose r-1}p^r(1-p)^{n-r}$$

Now realize that the RHS equals: $$np\sum_{r=1}^{n}{n-1 \choose r-1}p^{r-1}(1-p)^{n-r}=np(p+(1-p))^{n-1}=np$$

Answer (score 0):

You are starting this proof at the right way, but you are missing one important thing here: $(1) : (x+y)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n x^{n-k}y^k $.

I will show the proof, cause it is now pretty straightforward.

$\sum_{r=0}^n r Pr = \sum_{r=0}^n r \binom{n}{r} p^r(1-p)^{n-r} = \sum_{r=1}^n r \frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!} p^r(1-p)^{n-r}$ where we used that the first term is $0$.

$=\sum_{r=1}^n \frac{n!}{(r-1)!(n-r)!}p^r(1-p)^{n-r} = \sum_{r=1}^n n\cdot p \frac{(n-1)!}{(r-1)!((n-1)-(r-1))!} p^{r-1}(1-p)^{(n-1)-(r-1)}
=\sum_{r=1}^n n \cdot p \binom{n-1}{r-1}p^{r-1}(1-p)^{(n-1)-(r-1)}$

Now define $m=n-1, j=r-1$ and then it follows that

$=n\cdot p \sum_{j=0}^m \binom{m}{j} p^j (1-p)^{m-j} = n \cdot p (p+(1-p))^n = n \cdot p$ by (1)

Comment: so specified but I will learn some concepts like this soon :)